# pgadmin can't log in after update

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

Just updated pgadmin4 to version 4.8 and now it won't accept ssh tunnel password into server, I get the following error message:

```
Failed to decrypt the SSH tunnel password. Error: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8c in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Is there a way around this, I can't restart the database server at this time.

Answer (score 4):

In latest pgAdmin4 version they have increased the security of saved password by implementing master password feature, I think that is causing this issue, meantime you can rename `pgadmin4.db` to `pgadmin4.db_OLD` and restart pgAdmin4.

**Note:** You have to add the all the servers again.

**---------- UPDATE ----------**

It has been fixed now https://redmine.postgresql.org/issues/4320 and will be in 4.9.

You can try nightly builds though https://postgresql.org/ftp/pgadmin/pgadmin4/snapshots

Comment: Thankyou, I posted a bug report and they replied that it is a known issue that will be fixed in the next release. In the meantime, I just rolled back to the previous version I was using and that solved my problem. Thank you for your input.

Comment: I'm seeing this in version 4.7.0 as well.

Comment: Thanks. The nightly fixed it for me.

Comment: This fixed it for me without having to add all the servers again: Right click on server, click on 'Clear Saved Password'. It will ask for the password again.

Comment: Got the same upgrading from 4.6 to 4.11 on windows. Clear password AND shut down pgadmin server and start again fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

This also happened for me moving from 4.8.2 for Ubuntu 18.10 to 4.8.2 for Ubuntu 19.04 (different installs).  I was able to resolve this by restarting the postgres server with `sudo systemctl restart postgresql`

Answer (score 0):

As said Murtuza Z, in https://redmine.postgresql.org/issues/4320, you can get fixed server_manager.py and replace it at `(pgAdmin install dir)/web/pgadmin/utils/driver/psycopg2/server_manager.py`, then restart the pgadmin server.

You can get `server_manager.py`:

- It is attached in an issue info. < this worked for me.
- Get from snapshots provided by Murtuza Z in same directory.