# PgAdmin Error: Failed to decrypt the saved password

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

After updating my `pgAdmin` version to `V4-4.8` I can not login to my database anymore. I'm trying to login on `Windows 10`.

The error:

```
Failed to decrypt the saved password.
Error: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pgadmin can't log in after update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56443186/pgadmin-cant-log-in-after-update)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In PGAdmin 4.10 > Disconnect from Server > right click > Clear Saved Password
:)

Comment: Now I can use my old database with new version of PGAdmin 4-10. Thank you very much for your help.